# Can the priestess counter cheating?

Tags: red-dragon-inn

In Red Dragon Inn, the priestess has a counter card called "they might not know you're cheating but my goddess does" where they negate a cheating card only if they are still In the round of gambling.

The cheating card played was "what's that up your sleeve" by Zot the wizard and Pooky. This card takes control of then round of gambling and picks a player to force them to leave the round of gambling.

In this scenario Zot forced the priestess to leave and following that the priestess tried to counter it with the card mentioned above. An argument ensued about whether the priestess was allowed to do this or not. Does anyone know the official ruling of this? In my opinion since Zot played first and forced the priestess to leave she was no longer in the round of gambling and therefore not allowed to counter.

Answer (score 3):

When someone is being forced out of a round of gambling everyone has a chance to counter, including the person being forced out. The actual card does not finish resolving until counters have been played.

From the [official rules](http://slugfestgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/RDIRules.pdf) (page 3):

> **Forcing a Player to Leave a Round of Gambling**
>
> Some cards force a player to leave a Round of Gambling. When a player is forced out of the Round, each player, including the one being forced out, has a chance to respond (for example, with "Oh, I guess the Wench thought that was her tip...", "They might not know you're cheating, but my Goddess does!", or another anti-cheat card).

Comment: Thank you for the response. We found the ruling that says this. I feel like the priestess card is missleading based on what it says. Thank you

Comment: Easily misread, but the intent of it (and other cards with the same wording) are that you have to use it on a Cheat card that is directly affecting you.

Comment: @KenHerbert I don't agree with that. The intent is that you use it on a cheat card, and most often you'll want to use it to protect yourself, but there are all sorts of situations in gambling where you might want to use it on someone else or just to prevent the cheater using their card.

Comment: @Samthere Maybe I worded that comment a little off. By "directly affecting you" I meant that it affects you because you are still in the round of Gambling and it directly affects your chances of winning the gamble, I didn't mean it had to be a card that is only played directly on you.

Comment: The long and short of it is that whenever a card is played, all players have a chance to respond to it BEFORE the effect of the card occurs. When a cheat card is played that would force a player out, that player may respond to that card by using a counter-cheat card before they are removed by its effect. The only time they cannot is if they are prevented from negating the card (e.g. Kaylin (Red Dragon Inn 3), when Wulfric is Stalwart, prevents ALL other players from playing any card that would negate or ignore a card Kaylin played).